# can not get the data that pass via props react js

Tags: reactjs

look at my App.js Component

```
export default function App() {
const [userName, setUserName] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const jwt = localStorage.getItem("token");
      const user = jwtDecode(jwt);
      console.log("emp", user);
      setUserName(user);
    } catch (ex) {}
  });
  console.log("username", userName);
```

as u can see i decoded the token and after that i want to update the state, now look at the rest of the App.js Component:

```
 render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar {...userName} />
 </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
```

as u can see i want to pass the state as a prop to my Navbar Component but all i get is just only an empty object and that's why i can't use it as a props
here is the code :
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tharp-pmfm8y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is your user getting logged in the `console.log`?

Comment: Empty object is like you initialize the value in the `useState` so i think that maybe, your `jwtDecode()` is throwing an exception and you are not setting the value for the username.    Also, i think `userName` is a string, am i wrong? So i think you should pass it to the Navbar like `<Navbar userName={userName} />`   (cause `{...userName}` is valid if `userName` is an object with props, and you want to pass all of this props to the Navbar)

Comment: @jondoe
i updated the question,
as u know when we decode the token it has some attributes, i just want to get one of them which is the name of my user, look at the code below
 i can get and i see the result that i want exactly:
`console.log("emp", user);`
but when i want to update the state i cant see my user name

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use **async/await** directly inside *useEffect*!
But even you don't need it at all by getting value from *localStorage* so it should be like following :

```
export default function App() {
const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const { name } = jwtDecode(jwt);
    if (name) {
       console.log("emp", name);
       setUserName(name);
    }
  }, []);
```

Then what you did wrong as i see is that you are sending *userName* like **{...userName}** which is wrong then you'll receive it in child component as props object has index starting from 0 and the value of each prop it letter of userName's value so send it like this standard way pls :

```
<Navbar userName={userName} />
```

Or :

```
const props = {userName};
<Navbar {...props} />
```

Comment: tbh i did all this ways before but till now there it does not fixed the issue

Comment: impossible! can you show us <Navbar> component ?

Comment: here is the Navbar Component
`const Navbar = (props) => {
  const [currentUserName, setCurrentUserName] = useState(props);
  console.log("name", currentUserName);`

Comment: no man !
you should do this :
`const [currentUserName, setCurrentUserName] = useState(props.userName);`

Comment: u know sir 
when i log `currentUserName` it show me undefinded

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with how you passing the props. The better way is to pass the whole object and destructure it in child component.

Here is the working example;

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

// this is example token
const token =
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c";
useEffect(() => {
  const decoded: Decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  setUserData(decoded);
}, []);


// pass the props like This

return (
  <Navbar userData={userData} />
)
```

**Updated Answer**
in Navbar.jsx use props like this.

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const NavBar = ({ userData }) => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li className="nav-item active">
            <NavLink className="nav-link" to="login">
              {userData?.name}
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: there is an error 
` Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'userDatas' as it is null.`

Comment: so have you tried this with the token i have added? And try  console logging your decoded value. Also check if it actually populating the userData

Comment: u know sir 
i get the the token and i decode it successfully and i can see everything that i want inside it but when i want to update the state it does not update

Comment: please add you navBar component and also codesanbox if possible

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-tharp-pmfm8y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @HassanJalali please check the updated answer, tested and working fine locally

Comment: i test that but it return me a null value, u know i think when i want to update the State in my app.js component it's just does not happening and that's why i get the init values ,now  there is one question, is there any way to tell the the app.js component to get render only when the state is updated?